# Facebook graph api with native iPhone application

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to use the Facebook Graph API in a NATIVE iPhone Application. Has anybody been able to find a way to post images/message on a user's feed?

I have tried all possible ways to post a ‘picture’ (not a URL but a UIImage) on the feed and have been working on this for 2 weeks now.

If you go to facebook.com you can upload a picture from your computer on to the wall. I am using ASIHTTPRequest to work on facebook graph API.

This is the nearest I have gone to posting a picture on the feed. So if I have a `ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];`

The url is https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

Now to post a picture I do the following:

```
[request setPostValue:@"My Message" forKey:@"message"];

[request setPostValue:@"somepic.png" forKey:@"picture"];

[request setPostValue:@"Some Name" forKey:@"name"];

[request setPostValue:@"Some description" forKey:@"description];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

If you try this then everything works fine other than the picture being posted. A blank placeholder for the picture is though show on the feed.

Comment: This might get you started: http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api

Comment: Thank you but I have already gone through this page. The problem is I am not able to get a way to post messages/pictures to facebook.

Comment: Messages should be as easy as using the code from the above tutorial to login, then using the access_token in a request to do the post as specified in the docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. The problem is to post a image/message. Facebook is talking of curl in the link that you have given. 
curl it seems to be something related to PHP(I dont know much of PHP). I do not want to leave my app to do the processing. I wanted something that can work with NSURLRequest.

Comment: Facebook iOS sdk has a demo. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a method to help me do this.  Hope this is of some help.

Please read the tutorial on how to set up the Facebook SDK.

```
-(void) updateStatusWithText:(NSString *) fbTitle //Status title
                 andStoryURL:(NSString *) fbURL   //URL for the story
                    andStory:(NSString *) fbStory //The story
                    andImage:(NSString *) imageURL //Image to be displayed.
                   andPrompt:(NSString *) promptString{

    NSLog(@"updateStatusWithText");

    NSString *attachmentText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\","
                               "\"href\":\"%@\","
                               "\"description\":\"%@\","
                               "\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\","
                               "\"src\":\"%@\","
                               "\"href\":\"%@\"}],"
                               "\"properties\":{\"Uploaded from an iPhone\":{\"text\":\"AFL Fan\",\"href\":\"Your itunes apstore URL\"}}}", fbTitle, fbURL, fbStory,imageURL,fbURL];


    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    promptString,  @"user_message_prompt",

                                   //  actionLinksStr, @"properties",
                                   attachmentText, @"attachment",
                                   nil];
    NSLog (@"attachmentText : %@", attachmentText);


    [facebook dialog:@"stream.publish"
           andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];

}
```