# Facebook Graph API call not working in iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to write an iPhone application that allows a user to "Check-in" to a store using the Graph API method; something like

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
app_id, @"app_id",
@"111664535537155", @"place",
@"I just Checked Into A Retail Store", @"message", nil];

[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/checkins" andParams: params     andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

but I'm having no luck. I know I've setup the rest of the Facebook Connect stuff fine, since my dialog calls such as

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               app_id, @"app_id",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                               @"Test Post", @"caption",
                               @"Check out my Test Post", @"message",
                               nil];


[appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

works fine.  According to [This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app) Facebook Connect supports Graph API calls, and the authentication should be enough.

Am I missing something? What should I try doing to fix this?  I've taken a look at the other related questions on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions seems to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Does Anyone have Any ideas on how I should go about fixing this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook graph api with native iPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073542/facebook-graph-api-with-native-iphone-application)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to pass in the "coordinates" parameter. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ and look for checkins

Answer (score 0):

Did you prompt the user for "publish_checkins" [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)?

Comment: Yes, in my app delegate I create a facebook object like this:

`code`

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:ApiKey];

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",   @"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"user_checkins", @"friends_checkins", @"publish_checkins", nil] retain];

    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
`/code`

This is a shared app delegate through the rest of my project, and i've been successful in using it to make posts using the feed dialog calls (mentioned in the original post)